# Finding sibling of a link while using watir-WebDriver

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, webdriver

I'm using watir-WebDriver to automate a website test automation. I have to get to the Sibling link.

looks like this

Something > Something 2 > current page title
(link1)        (link2)        (text1)

I have the class id of the text1, and I have to go back to the Something 2 by clicking on the link2.

How do I get this.

Comment: “An Example Would Be Handy Right About Now” (http://www.exampler.com/blog/2007/08/07/marketing-mania-continues/)

Comment: if you can give an example in HTML format it would be most helpful, the way you've expressed it I'm not sure what is a container, and what is next to a container etc..  Actual HTML would be way way more helpful in terms of allowing folks to provide better suggestions or code examples.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the sibling link with elements_by_xpath.

example

---

HTML source:

<a href="foo">bar</a><p class="baz">text</p>

---

watir-webdriver script:

p(:class,'baz').elements_by_xpath('preceding-sibling::*')[-1]

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a common parent for the two siblings, you can go to that parent, then select the element from that point using something like this:

source html:

```
<tr>
  <th>No. of films</th>
  <td>7</th>
</tr>
```

scrape (`@b` is the browser object)

```
@b.th(:text => "No. of films").parent.tds.first.text
#=> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

If (text1) is a child of (link2) you might try:

(text1).parent

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you have some kind of container element like a like a div, and inside it are two links and some text.  What is not clear is if the text belongs to the outer container, or is inside a container of its own.  Given you say you have the 'classid'  (is that the class?  or the id?) of the text, I'm going to presume that it is in it's own container element.

In that case

```
browser.element(:class, 'value').parent.link(:index, 2).click
```

That's the best I can do without an actual sample of HTML, a clearer model of the DOM

Answer (score 0):

As all the previous answer says, you gotta have a reference point above this hierarchy. Then `browser.p(:id, 'known').parent.links[1].click` would do the job. But if you really really don't, try this hopelessly simple approach:

`browser.link(:text => 'Something 2').click`